# Adding a bookmark or a web page to the reading list in Safari causes freeze

Tags: safari, performance, bookmarks, reading-list

When I try to add a bookmark or a web page to the reading list in safari it freezes.

How do I solve this problem and what is causing it?

> Systeminfo
>
> Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: Can you expand on your question, Safari Version/OS would be good, and whether this has always failed, or is a recent thing etc.

Comment: Do you have bookmark syncing turned on in iCloud? If so, reading lists are also synced and maybe it's a problem with syncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Quit Safari (Make a backup of all the data of Safari)
2. Delete all Files in `~Library/Safari/`

**Caution:** This will delete all information stored in Safari. Safari will react as if it would have been freshly installed.

1. Start Safari (Safari will reproduce all files you deleted)

Voilà! Error solved the brutal way. Safari is able again to add bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall Safari.

1. Uninstall by...

   - ...dragging `/Applications/Safari.app` to the trash.
   - ...using a free [cleaning tool](http://freemacsoft.net/#). This tool will also remove preferences files in the library. Therefore bookmarks and extensions will be removed aswell.
2. Download Safari from the [apple website](http://www.apple.com/safari/) and reinstall it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I did exactly both steps and it doesn't remove my bookmarks, cache etc. etc. I searched for a de-installation instruction but it seems that it isn't possible to remove safari completely from the system

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when i added a bookmark and imported my bookmarks from my old iMac - and it is syncing with icloud - just diasable icloud and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found a lot easier solution for those who stumble upon this problem and here is the link to the original answer;
[Apple forum link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251846639?answerId=253762593022#253762593022)

but basically;

> In my case the issue went away after unchecking "Develop >
> Automatically Show Web Inspector for JSContexts". I guess I enabled a
> while ago to debug something but forgot to disable it - would have
> expected that setting to not be sticky across Safari relaunches.